# No Bluetooth Adapter/Intel Centrino N1030 11230BNHMW

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, intel-wireless

Laptop

Gateway NE56R41u

Wireless Card

PCIe half mini Intel Centrino N-1030 11230BNHMW

I took this Intel Centrino card out of my Dell Inspiron N4110 to replace with something compatible for wifi with OSX for hackintosh.  I want to add bluetooth to my Gateway NE56R41U, so I took the existing PCIe half mini card out, and put this one in.  Wifi works great in Ubuntu, but bluetooth tells me no bluetooth adapters found and rfkill list displays only this:

```
0:  acer-wireless:  Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked:  no
         Hard blocked:  no
2:  phy0:  Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked:  no
         Hard blocked:  no
```

Nothing bluetooth wise shows up in there.  I looked in the BIOS and its pretty bare bones and limited, no options for anything USB or Bluetooth in there at all.

Any ideas on how to get bluetooth working?